# How to use complex numbers in a map c++

Tags: c++

I have been sitting for hours now trying to find a way to use complex values in a std::map. My code is

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> coord; // bin coordinates
std::vector<std::string> ref; //A1,D4,...
std::map<std::string,std::complex<double>> bin; //coordinates and reference
std::string letter_ref[] = {"H","G","F","E","D","C","B","A"};
std::string int_ref[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
double x=0;
double y=0;
for(int i=0;i<8;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<8;++j){
        coord.push_back(std::complex<double>(7-i,j));
        ref.push_back(letter_ref[i]+int_ref[j]);
        bin.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::complex<double>>(letter_ref[i]+int_ref[j], (7-i,j)));
        //bin.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::complex<double>>(letter_ref[i]+int_ref[j], (7-x,y)));
        ++y;
    }
    ++x;
}
```

This is a part of a constructor. The reason that I have a map and two vectors that are supposed to show the same thing is because I started to use vectors, but found it to be a pain to work with. But I wanted to keep the old vectors for some more time to get the map right first.

However the map does not give the intended result. Printing the map with

```
std::map<std::string,std::complex<double>>::iterator it;
int i = 0;
for(it=bin.begin();it!=bin.end();++it){
    std::cout<<"["<<it->first<<","<<it->second<<"] ";
    if ((i+1) % 8 == 0)// & i>0)
        std::cout<<"\n";
    ++i;
}
```

Does in the first case (uncommented) show that the imaginary part is 0, but the first part is correct. The second case (commented) still shows a 0 value for the imaginary part, but the real part does, instead of giving the values 0-7, give values 0-63.

Does anyone know how to properly use complex numbers in a map?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).  Your code references variables that aren't declared.  It's hard to tell what you are actually trying to do and what is going wrong.

Comment: What does the above `cb` instance refer to?

Comment: opps I had forgot about that. However the answer down below was quite clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the c'tor you want to store a complex number in your map with real part `7-i` and imaginary part `j`. You do this by passing `(7-i, j)`, but this will not invoke the c'tor of [`std::complex<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) the way you might expect (i.e. with `re=7-i` and `im=j`).

What you're actually using in your code is the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). From Wikipedia:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

So by passing `(7-i, j)` to the c'tor of `std::complex<double>` instead of creating an imaginary number with real part `7-i` and imaginary part `j` you create a complex number with real part `j` and no imaginary part. So just replace your line

```
bin.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::complex<double>>(letter_ref[i]+int_ref[j], (7-i,j)));
```

with

```
bin.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::complex<double>>(letter_ref[i]+int_ref[j], std::complex<double>(7-i,j)));
```

to make it work as expected. This explicitly invokes the c'tor of `std::complex<double>` with the parameters you specified.

Comment: Without any modifications, the original posted code produces a compiler warning on my RAD Studio - C++Builder Win64 compiler.  The warning says on the `bin.insert(...)` line: `expression result unused`.  In case it is not known, the 3.1 LLVM (CLang++) is the basis for the 64-bit Windows C++Builder compiler.  @patrik Did the compiler being used issue a similar warning?  This answer compiles and runs with no warnings on my system.

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer! I guess I should have thought about this. And @CPlusPlusOOAandD my compiler which is the standard Visual studio Express 2012 compiler did not warn me. It all went through smoothly, except that it was not the result intended.

Comment: @patrik Is there a `-Wall` or similar option that VS Express 2012 has?  I have never used the 2012 release.  My most recent VS use is VS Ultimate 2010, mainly for C# and C# Web Services.

Comment: Actually I do not know. I come from a java background and is quite new to c++. Since I have quite a lot to learn still I have not explored the full range of possiblities of my IDE.

Comment: you should definitely turn all warnings on. This will really make your development easier. Most of problems posted in SO show instantly, when warnings are enabled.

Comment: @zoska thank you I will try to do so. I was still unaware of that some warnings were turned off, so I thank you for pointing it out.